Custom extensible framework ExtJs - catch popup window rendering
I'm using a custom extensible framework (extends abstract framework) and I want to get a component that is accessible only when a popup window has been rendered. If I use devtools, open the popup and use Ext.query("field[name=ddsDefautProperty]") I have a return value. But until this popup is called I can't access it. Any tips on how to "catch" rendering of this field or the popup ?
Thank you ahead

Try using listeners on afterrender event in your component.
Like this:
listeners: {
        afterrender: function(){
             Ext.query("field[name=ddsDefautProperty]")
        }

Or initComponent (but then your element should already be in the DOM):
initComponent() {
        .....
        this.callParent(arguments);
    },

I may have misunderstood, but then you'd better provide some code of your own.

Hello,
Thank you for your answer. The thing is I have a screen (panels and tabs). But the element i'm trying to reach for is rendered in  popup window that doesn't exists until i have clicked on a button of the main screen. I tried to add an event listener on this button that call a function who call Ext.component.CompnentQuery() but i'm not able to catch it. Ill try to post my code :).

What ExtJS version and what kind of popup window do you use? Can you show its class? Making fiddle would be the best.

From your question I take it that you are using Ext.Dialog.
It looks like you are struggling with getting the Dialog`s Textfield.
First, I will show how to grab items via up - down.
Second, I will present a possible way to grab the value from the textfield.
The problem with the dialog is, that the parent is the viewport and hence you have no control from your current view.
Classic
const w = Ext.create('Ext.Window', {
    id     : 'foo',
    ownerCt: this.getView();
});

w.up();                   // ==> this.getView()
Ext.get('foo').component; // ==> window

Modern
const d = Ext.create('Ext.Dialog', {
    id    : 'foo',
    parent: this.getView();
});

d.up();                   // ==> this.getView()
Ext.get('foo').component; // ==> window

Solution
Ext.define('Fiddle.Main', {
     extend: 'Ext.Panel',

     viewModel: {
         data: {
             dialog_masterpiece: 'this will be filled by the textfield inside the dialog'
         }
     },

     title: 'I am parent',

     bind: {
         html: '{dialog_masterpiece}'
     },

     buttons: {
         back: {
             flex: 1,
             text: 'create dialog',
             ui: 'action',
             handler: function (btn) {
                 const view = btn.up('panel');

                 Ext.create('Ext.Dialog', {
                     viewModel: {
                         parent: view.getViewModel(),
                     },

                     closable: true,
                     title: 'My Popup',

                     items: [{
                         xtype: 'textfield',
                         label: 'TextField',
                         bind: {
                             value: '{dialog_masterpiece}'
                         }
                     }]
                 }).show();
             }
         }
     }
 });

The solution is to add a viewModel to the dialog with a parent viewModel.
But even without the parent viewModel you could use this approach, because the standard parent viewModel is the viewport. The only problem might be, that the highest possible viewModel gets polluted.
The second possible solution, might be to handle things on close of the dialog and write the solution to the parent.
The third solution might be to add "field[name=ddsDefautProperty]" to a controller control change event
Ext.define('Fiddle.MainController', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.ViewController',
    alias: 'controller.main',

    control: {
        'dialog textfield': {
            change: 'onTextfieldChange'
        }
    },

    onTextfieldChange: function (textfield, value) {
        this.getView().setTitle(value)
    },

    onCreateDialog: function () {
        const view = this.getView();

        Ext.create('Ext.Dialog', {
            // use this to use the viewModel way
            viewModel: {
                parent: view.getViewModel(),
            },

            // use this to choose the viewcontroller - control
            parent: view,

            closable: true,
            title: 'My Popup',

            items: [{
                xtype: 'textfield',
                label: 'TextField',
                bind: {
                    value: '{dialog_masterpiece}'
                }
            }]
        }).show();
    }
});


Hello :)
First I  want to thank you for your help ! I'll try this method and get back to you if needed. Thank you again
